# Problem defining a polygon

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, polygons

I have two polygons that are very similar as:

```
poly1 =
 Polygon[{{1, 19/1650}, {2, 19/1650}, {3, 19/1650}, {4, 19/1650}, {5,   19/1650}, {6, 19/1650}, {7, 19/1650}, {8, 19/1650}, {9, 19/ 1650}, {10, 19/1650}, {11, 19/1650}, {12, 17/1650}, {13, 17/   1650}, {14, 17/1650}, {15, 17/1650}, {16, 17/1650}, {17, 17/   1650}, {18, 17/1650}, {19, 17/1650}, {20, 17/1650}, {21, 17/   1650}, {22, 17/1650}, {23, 17/1650}, {24, 17/1650}, {25, 17/   1650}, {26, 17/1650}, {27, 1/110}, {28, 1/110}, {29, 1/110}, {30,    1/110}, {31, 1/110}, {32, 1/110}, {33, 1/110}, {34, 13/1650}, {35,    13/1650}, {36, 13/1650}, {37, 13/1650}, {38, 13/1650}, {39, 1/   150}, {40, 1/150}, {41, 1/150}, {42, 1/150}, {43, 3/550}, {44, 3/   550}, {45, 3/550}, {46, 7/1650}, {47, 7/1650}, {48, 1/330}, {49, 1/   330}, {50, 1/   550}, {50, -(1/1650)}, {49, -(1/550)}, {48, -(1/330)}, {47, -(1/    330)}, {46, -(1/330)}, {45, -(7/1650)}, {44, -(7/1650)}, {43, -(7/    1650)}, {42, -(3/550)}, {41, -(3/550)}, {40, -(3/550)}, {39, -(1/    150)}, {38, -(1/150)}, {37, -(1/150)}, {36, -(1/150)}, {35, -(1/    150)}, {34, -(1/150)}, {33, -(13/1650)}, {32, -(13/1650)}, {31, -(    13/1650)}, {30, -(13/1650)}, {29, -(13/1650)}, {28, -(13/    1650)}, {27, -(13/1650)}, {26, -(13/1650)}, {25, -(1/    110)}, {24, -(1/110)}, {23, -(1/110)}, {22, -(1/110)}, {21, -(1/    110)}, {20, -(1/110)}, {19, -(1/110)}, {18, -(1/110)}, {17, -(1/    110)}, {16, -(1/110)}, {15, -(1/110)}, {14, -(1/110)}, {13, -(1/    110)}, {12, -(1/110)}, {11, -(1/110)}, {10, -(1/110)}, {9, -(1/    110)}, {8, -(1/110)}, {7, -(1/110)}, {6, -(1/110)}, {5, -(1/    110)}, {4, -(1/110)}, {3, -(1/110)}, {2, -(1/110)}, {1, -(1/    110)}}];
```

and

```
poly2 = 
  Polygon[{{1, 19/1650}, {2, 19/1650}, {3, 19/1650}, {4, 19/1650}, {5,    19/1650}, {6, 19/1650}, {7, 19/1650}, {8, 19/1650}, {9, 19/   1650}, {10, 19/1650}, {11, 19/1650}, {12, 19/1650}, {13, 19/   1650}, {14, 19/1650}, {15, 19/1650}, {16, 17/1650}, {17, 17/   1650}, {18, 17/1650}, {19, 17/1650}, {20, 17/1650}, {21, 17/   1650}, {22, 17/1650}, {23, 17/1650}, {24, 17/1650}, {25, 17/   1650}, {26, 17/1650}, {27, 17/1650}, {28, 1/110}, {29, 1/110}, {30,    1/110}, {31, 1/110}, {32, 1/110}, {33, 1/110}, {34, 1/110}, {35,    13/1650}, {36, 13/1650}, {37, 13/1650}, {38, 13/1650}, {39, 13/   1650}, {40, 1/150}, {41, 1/150}, {42, 1/150}, {43, 1/150}, {44, 3/   550}, {45, 3/550}, {46, 3/550}, {47, 7/1650}, {48, 7/1650}, {49, 1/   330}, {50, 1/330}, {51, 1/   550}, {51, -(1/1650)}, {50, -(1/550)}, {49, -(1/330)}, {48, -(1/    330)}, {47, -(1/330)}, {46, -(7/1650)}, {45, -(7/1650)}, {44, -(3/    550)}, {43, -(3/550)}, {42, -(3/550)}, {41, -(3/550)}, {40, -(1/    150)}, {39, -(1/150)}, {38, -(1/150)}, {37, -(1/150)}, {36, -(1/    150)}, {35, -(13/1650)}, {34, -(13/1650)}, {33, -(13/    1650)}, {32, -(13/1650)}, {31, -(13/1650)}, {30, -(13/    1650)}, {29, -(13/1650)}, {28, -(13/1650)}, {27, -(1/    110)}, {26, -(1/110)}, {25, -(1/110)}, {24, -(1/110)}, {23, -(1/    110)}, {22, -(1/110)}, {21, -(1/110)}, {20, -(1/110)}, {19, -(1/    110)}, {18, -(1/110)}, {17, -(1/110)}, {16, -(1/110)}, {15, -(1/    110)}, {14, -(1/110)}, {13, -(1/110)}, {12, -(1/110)}, {11, -(1/    110)}, {10, -(1/110)}, {9, -(1/110)}, {8, -(1/110)}, {7, -(1/    110)}, {6, -(1/110)}, {5, -(1/110)}, {4, -(1/110)}, {3, -(1/    110)}, {2, -(1/110)}, {1, -(1/110)}}]
```

Visually they look very similar, only that `poly2` is a bit larger. But I can use `poly2` to do all sort of functions. For example:

```
Area[poly2] == 457/550
```

In contrast, I cannot evaluate `poly`1 in any expression. Everything I evaluate returns unevaluated.

Does anybody have any ideas about why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in version 12.0:

```
poly1 = Polygon[{{1, 19/1650}, {2, 19/1650}, {3, 19/1650}, {4, 
 19/1650}, {5, 19/1650}, {6, 19/1650}, {7, 19/1650}, {8, 
 19/1650}, {9, 19/1650}, {10, 19/1650}, {11, 19/1650}, {12, 
 17/1650}, {13, 17/1650}, {14, 17/1650}, {15, 17/1650}, {16, 
 17/1650}, {17, 17/1650}, {18, 17/1650}, {19, 17/1650}, {20, 
 17/1650}, {21, 17/1650}, {22, 17/1650}, {23, 17/1650}, {24, 
 17/1650}, {25, 17/1650}, {26, 17/1650}, {27, 1/110}, {28, 
 1/110}, {29, 1/110}, {30, 1/110}, {31, 1/110}, {32, 1/110}, {33, 
 1/110}, {34, 13/1650}, {35, 13/1650}, {36, 13/1650}, {37, 
 13/1650}, {38, 13/1650}, {39, 1/150}, {40, 1/150}, {41, 
 1/150}, {42, 1/150}, {43, 3/550}, {44, 3/550}, {45, 3/550}, {46, 
 7/1650}, {47, 7/1650}, {48, 1/330}, {49, 1/330}, {50, 
 1/550}, {50, -(1/1650)}, {49, -(1/550)}, {48, -(1/
    330)}, {47, -(1/330)}, {46, -(1/330)}, {45, -(7/
    1650)}, {44, -(7/1650)}, {43, -(7/1650)}, {42, -(3/
    550)}, {41, -(3/550)}, {40, -(3/550)}, {39, -(1/
    150)}, {38, -(1/150)}, {37, -(1/150)}, {36, -(1/
    150)}, {35, -(1/150)}, {34, -(1/150)}, {33, -(13/
    1650)}, {32, -(13/1650)}, {31, -(13/1650)}, {30, -(13/
    1650)}, {29, -(13/1650)}, {28, -(13/1650)}, {27, -(13/
    1650)}, {26, -(13/1650)}, {25, -(1/110)}, {24, -(1/
    110)}, {23, -(1/110)}, {22, -(1/110)}, {21, -(1/
    110)}, {20, -(1/110)}, {19, -(1/110)}, {18, -(1/
    110)}, {17, -(1/110)}, {16, -(1/110)}, {15, -(1/
    110)}, {14, -(1/110)}, {13, -(1/110)}, {12, -(1/
    110)}, {11, -(1/110)}, {10, -(1/110)}, {9, -(1/110)}, {8, -(1/
    110)}, {7, -(1/110)}, {6, -(1/110)}, {5, -(1/110)}, {4, -(1/
    110)}, {3, -(1/110)}, {2, -(1/110)}, {1, -(1/110)}}];Area[poly1] Perimeter[poly1]
```

> 53/66, $ \frac{\sqrt{680626}}{55}+\frac{68494}{825}$

Comment: It seems there was a problem before the update. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I remove just one specific point, `{12, 17/1650}`. from `poly1` to create a new polygon everything works as expected.

```
newPoly = DeleteCases[poly1, {12, 17/1650}, {2}];
Graphics[
  {{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], poly1}, {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Red], newPoly}},
  AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image: plot]

```
Area[newPoly]
```

> `221/275`

```
Perimeter[poly3]
```

> `1/825 (67669 + 14 Sqrt[680626] + Sqrt[2722501])`

```
RegionCentroid[newPoly]
```

> `{14515/663, 1273/1640925}`

I think you have created a polygon that breaks some to region mensuration functions. I also note that `RegionMeasure[poly1]` reports the error

> RegionMeasure::nmet: Unable to compute the measure of region Polygon[{{1,19/1650},{2,19/1650},{3,19/1650},{4,19/1650},{5,19/1650},{6,19/1650},{7,19/1650},{8,19/1650},{9,19/1650},{10,19/1650},<<32>>,{43,3/550},{44,3/550},{45,3/550},{46,7/1650},{47,7/1650},{48,1/330},{49,1/330},{50,1/550},<<50>>}].

I recommend you report this problem to Wolfram Research tech support.

Comment: But how would you know which point to remove so that it works?

Comment: @NinjaCowAndForks. I coded a binary search.